# Select all ids for of the friends for a particular user

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Need some assistance from SQL experts out there.   Quick overview of the structure of my two tables that I'm looking to query from.

- users table

  - id - (int) primary key
  - name - (string)
- friends table

  - id - (int) primary key
  - toid - int
  - fromid - int

friends table holds the friendship relationship between users.  The tricky part is that it holds two records per friendship.

So for example if we have three users in the database with id 1, 2, 3 and their names are Rob, John and Adam respectively.

If Rob and John are friends, the friends table has the following two entries:

id  toid   fromid

1   1   2

2   2   1

There are also situations where there is only one entry in the friends table.  This happens when a request has been sent by one person but not excepted by the recipient yet.

What I am trying to accomplish is to select all id and names for of the friends for a particular user.  (Friends being the ones that have both entries in the friends table, not just one).

What I have tried so far gives me list of ids for both friends and users who have either sent or received a request for a particular user.  Below is the closest I've gotten.

> SELECT DISTINCT 
>     users.ID userid 
>     users.name name 
>   FROM users 
>   INNER JOIN friends 
>   ON users.id = friends.fromid OR users.id = friends.toid 
>   WHERE (friends.fromid = 1 OR friends.toid = 1) AND users.ID != 1

Comment: @GordonLinoff thank you.  That was a typo.  Its fixed now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will give you the list of ID with two way friendship with `@userID`.

Check **[Fiddle Demo](http://rextester.com/DOQMJ67860)**

```
INSERT INTO friends
    (`ID`, `toid`, `fromid`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 2),
    (2, 2, 1),
    (3, 1, 3),
    (4, 3, 1),
    (5, 2, 3)
;
```

- with `@userID = 1` you get `{2, 3}`
- with `@userID = 2` you get `{1}`  `//2 sent to 3 but not receive it back`
- with `@userID = 3` you get `{1}`

QUERY

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN toid = @userID THEN fromid 
                                 ELSE toid 
        END as myFriendID
FROM friends
WHERE  toid = @userID OR fromid = @userID
GROUP BY LEAST(toid, fromid), GREATEST(toid, fromid)
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

Comment: What does the CASE block do here?

Comment: Imagine you are looking for `@userID = 8`  ... if you have `(1,8)` or `(8,1)` `CASE` will return `1`

Comment: It seems to work.  Thank you.  I'm trying to understand how the flow goes and am still confused by the CASE block.

Comment: Check fiddle demo I include. In that example you have `(1,2)` and `(2,1)` if you are looking for `@userid = 1` on both cases you will get `2` because `CASE` check for `@userID` and return the other field

Comment: Thank you.  Now it makes sense!   Any way of accomplishing this with joins?

Comment: you can use `WHERE  @userID IN (toid, fromid)`

Comment: What do the LEAST(toid, fromid), GREATEST(toid, fromid) in the GROUP BY section do?

Comment: I completely missed one part of my requirement.  I need to query to also return the name of the user along with their ID.  Could you modify your code to return name as well please.

Comment: Cant you do that? Is like you ask me for a Hot Dog, and then ask me to add the ketchup :(

Comment: lol. Nice analogy!  I'm not familiar with the syntax you used.  I'll give it a shot!  ;)

Comment: I like to help, but you have to put some effort too ;)

Comment: Done my man!  Thanks for the help!  I needed to step away for a minute and then come back to it!